# Issue connecting to Postgres SQL on AWS T2 micro server

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to run Postgres SQL on a AWS t2 micro server. I have seen the documentation about changing the config files and opening up 0.0.0.0/32 and ::/0. I have done all of that and still can not connect remotely.

Can this even be done with a micro server?
Is there another setting within AWS I need to change for this server to accept incoming connections?

I am trying to produce a proof of concept so I am keeping it as small as possible.

Comment: Please [edit] your question title to describe the problem you're having or question you're asking. Your current title is a useless repetition of tag information, which shouldn't be in the title at all. Your title should be clear and descriptive enough that a future site user who is skimming a list of search results will understand the content. For suggestions on how to write a good title, see [ask].

Comment: Man I am stumped. I have tried all of the suggestions about changing the two config files and not using the default security group in AWS. The one I am using I have set the source to be the 0.0.0.0/32 and ::0/

I still cannot connect.  Ugh! Very frustrating

Answer (score 1):

I do this all the time, it works fine with t2.micro. But you also need to set the security group to allow connections from the outside to get in.  The normal default SG doesn't allow it.

Comment: Thanks for the replay.

I'm kind of a nube when it comes to the AWS Console. The console shows I have  5 incoming entries.

2 are for Postgres. Source 0.0.0.0/32 and the other ::/0

What other permission do I need to add to get the connection open?

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I figured out what was wrong. Although I got all the configurations for PostGres done, I had to make an incoming rule in Windows Defender Firewall to open the 5432 port on the server. As soon as I did that, I could connect.